# Conjecture on number of positive roots of polynomial

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Let $n \geq 2$, $b \in (0,1)$ and $0 < a < \frac{b}{n-1}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. I have the conjecture (though I'm unable to prove it for general $n$) that the polynomial

$f(x;a,b,n) := \frac{(b-a+x)^n-x^n}{n}+(1-b-a)(b-a+x)^{n-1} - a(n-1)(1-b)(b-a+x)^{n-2}$

has at most one positive root $x$ in the range $[0, a]$.

For $n=2$, this is trivial, as $f(x;a,b,2)$ is linear in $x$. For $n=3$, it is easy to show that $f(x;a,b,3)$ is strictly convex given the parameter assumptions, and one can proceed from there. But for higher $n$, I could not come up with a promising proof strategy.

I was hoping that with some appropriate transformation of $x$, I could apply Descartes' rule of signs or related theorems, but I also don't see how.

Context: Showing this would help establishing uniqueness of the solution to a specific economic model.

Any ideas how to attack this problem would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone cares, I managed to prove this finally. The trick is to write $f(x;a,b,n)$ as proper polynomial in $x$ using the Binomial Theorem, which, after a couple of manipulations, lets us apply Descartes' rule of signs. In particular, it turns out that given the parameter assumptions, the coefficients of $P(x)$ are either all positive (no solution), or there is unique cutoff exponent $k^*$ such that the coefficients are positive for all terms with exponent $k \geq k^*$, and negative for all terms with exponent $k < k^*$.